# Create a compoment to render on main component, and triggerd from a function in different component

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i want to build for myself a DeleteModal in Next.js.

i want someting like `sonner`

```
import { Toaster, toast } from 'sonner' //import Toaster to render in layout.js and toast.succes() to be called in different component without to put Toaster again

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Toaster /> // this is in layout.js


      <button onClick={() => toast('My first toast')}> // and this in different component
        Give me a toast
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

how i can do this? in react/nextjs? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use app component as a container component to manage state to have all these components and call the onTriggerToast from that different component.
If i'm following you correctly something like this.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Layout from './Layout';
import DifferentComponent from './DifferentComponent';
import { Toaster, toast } from 'sonner'

const App = () => {
  const [showToast, setShowToast] = useState(false);

  const handleToast = () => {
   // Manage toast state accordingly here
   setShowToast(true);
   toast(message);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Layout showToast={showToast} />
      <DifferentComponent onTriggerToast={() => handleToast('My first toast')} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```